# Install4j Detect Upgrade is RadioNewInstallation so i can delete existing services

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to detect if the user has selected: `RadioNewInstallation=No, install into a different directory.` I want to completely remove the product and the services installed. Our product doesn't support multiple instances of the tomcat service. How do I do this on an upgrade scenario. I know that I have `context.getBooleanVariable("sys.confirmedUpdateInstallation")` to tell me that it is an in-place-upgrade. But I don't know the variable that are available if it is a clean-wipe-upgrade. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the user selects another installation directory with the "Installation location" screen, the installation directory will still be set to the previous installation directory.

You can add a "Display progress" screen, set its condition expression to

```
Boolean.FALSE.equals(context.getVariable("sys.confirmedUpdateInstallation"))
```

and add an "Uninstall previous installation" action to it.

Comment: Thank you I am trying it out to see how it works. I will update you if it does what I need.